# Multiple call to an api but restriction of time

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to call an api with different @RequestParam values, but any of the request takes time cancel the request and call the api with next param value

I have used java 8 completableFuture with a time restriction of 3 seconds but sometime it fails to execute correctly on server

```
 public class callApi {

      public void requestApi(){

       //I have a list of values
       List<Integer> paramValues = Arrays.asList(100, 101, 102);

       //Now I want to call an api throw service layer
       for(Integer param : paramValues) {
           List<ResponseResult> result = anyService.getResults(param);
        //if any of the request take time more than two second i 
          //have to 
         // cancel the request and call the api with different param 
        //iterated 
          //through the for loop

        //i am using completableFuture like this 
        /*
        CompletableFuture<List<ResponseResult>> completableFuture = 
              CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                        return anyService.getResults(param);
                    }).exceptionally(ex -> null);
         result = completableFuture.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      */
      }
     }
    }
```

Some time it gives null result and sometime it works fine. Is there any other method of implying this

Comment: "but sometime it fails to execute correctly on server" doesn't actually indicate what your problem is.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sometime it gives result correctly but sometime it fails to give result, gives empty or null for the same request

Comment: (Assuming you use the commented code, not the syncronous call) If you at least log something inside `.exceptionally()` block - you'll see what the problem is. Right now it completes with null result precisely because of the exception being thrown, and you ignore that exception. Without knowing what the exception was, we can't help.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov can you provide any alternative for this

Comment: @Sonukumar, I don't understand what would you expect as an alternative. What's wrong with existing code?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov any other solution to implement the same functionality and get the data other than my commented code

Comment: @Sonukumar, I probably can think of a couple, but why? Your question states that it works fine, unless request to server has failed. You can't compensate for remote server failure using different strategy on a client - unless you repeat the call. And it sounds like you already do that.